# Употребление предлогов "про" и "о"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Когда употребляется предлог "про", а когда "о"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В русском языке есть предлог "о-". Предлог "про-" - украинизм.
Примеры: *"об этом", "о деле", "о том, как..."*

Comment: Ответ не убедителен!Русские активно пользуются предлогом "Про"!Хотите сказать, что это влияние украинского языка?!

Comment: Радищев: "В законе никого бранить не велено, и всякому свобода есть жаловаться. Но если кто *про* кого скажет правду, бранью ли то почитать, того в законе нет".

Answer (score 0):

Про - просторечие, о - книжное.